# How to get contents of a tables based on left join on two other tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `categories` table and a `files` table. there is a `category_record_mm` table for storing the relationships.
I want to get categories of a file, for that I have written a `JOIN` statement, but JOIn is complaining that `files`.`uid` is not a valid column. what I actuallay want is, it should give me all categories if  `category_record_mm`.`foreign_uid` is equal to some id.
This is what I have written :

```
SELECT * FROM `categories`
LEFT JOIN `category_record_mm` ON `category_record_mm`.`foreign_uid` = `files`.`uid`
WHERE (`category_record_mm`.`foreign_uid` = 123 )
```

Comment: Is there a relation between `categories` and `category_record_mm` **or** between `categories` and `files` ?

Comment: The `category_record_mm` holds uid of `categories`  and `files`.
`category_record_mm` purpose is to hold record of what file has a relationship with which category

Comment: You are not use the `files` table in select or join section..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing 1 `JOIN`, the one between `categories` and `category_record_mm`

This is like having 3 towns, `A`, `B` and `C`, with a bridge between `A` and `B` and another one between `B` and `C`. You can't go from `A` to `C` without using the bridge between `A` and `B`

```
SELECT * FROM `categories`
LEFT JOIN `category_record_mm` ON `category_record_mm`.`categories_uid` = `categories`.`uid`
LEFT JOIN `files` ON `category_record_mm`.`foreign_uid` = `files`.`uid`
WHERE (`category_record_mm`.`foreign_uid` = 123 )
```

`categories_uid` being the foreign key referencing the table `categories` and `categories`.`uid` being the primary key of `categories`

Comment: Thanks for the help, unfortunatly I can't Vote up because I am new in SO, But it did help and work.

Comment: No worries, as long as you understood

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the categories, you do not need to reference the `files` table.  You simply need to phrase the query correctly:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM categories c JOIN
     category_record_mm cr
     ON cr.categories_uid = c.uid
WHERE cr.foreign_uid = 123;
```

Notes:

- The `JOIN` between the two table is on the *category* columns, not the *file* columns.
- Table aliases make the query much easier to write and to read.
- You have the file uid in `category_record_mm`.  You are filtering on that, so you don't need to join the `files` table.